# CSS Inputfield & -button position for questionsystem

Tags: html, css, variables, input, position

I have a problem **positioning an inputfield with variable size and a post button with fixed size** inside of a div with fixed "outer-margin".

**I've provided a [jfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jgHAA/) where you can see the wrong version.**

Here you can see my problem:

**Wrong version:** [Actual website](http://d.pr/i/KUZj)

**"Should-be" version:** [This is what it should look like](http://d.pr/i/swX2)

Textual description:

As you can see in the 2nd picture, it's important for me that the bottom-part always sits on the bottom...

```
.submitform {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    ...more on jfiddle...
}
```

... and the post-button always on the right. The bottom-part should have the same gap on the left and right as the upper-part. The difficult thing is, that the inputfield should have flexible size but should take all the space between left gap and post-button.

I hope you can help me because hours of trying and searching on the web didn't brought me the right solution.

Comment: Why is `width: 87%;` on `.submitform`? Don't you want it to be as wide as the questions?

Comment: @KatieK he wants the element to be fixed-position at the bottom. If he doesn't set a width (or `left`/`right`), the element will collapse to the width of the two inputs it contains.

Comment: @Shmiddty - So why not `width: 100%` along with `box-sizing: border-box`?

Comment: @KatieK because border-box doesn't account for margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jgHAA/1/

```
.submitform {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    /* Instead of applying margin and width, simply set the bottom, left, 
       and right properties to 13px */
    bottom: 13px;  
    left: 13px;
    right: 13px;
    /*box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);*/
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 7px;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

to have the textbox fill the width, you can use the same technique: http://jsfiddle.net/jgHAA/2/

```
.submitform  #post_input {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 3px;
    /* set left and right, and z-index to make it appear behind the button.*/
    left:7px;
    right:7px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: With this the problem is, that the inputfield stays to small on larger screens. It doesn't fill up the space to the post-button (as you can see on the 2nd image that it should adjust its size). And you can't add "width:100%" to the input-field because this would push the post-button in the next line.